# How to check if TreeMap<String, ArrayList<String>> contains a value? in Java

Tags: java

I'm just wondering how to check if TreeMap> contains a value in Java?
For Example:

```
/*I have TreeMap<String,ArrayList<String>> map with these elements
 * {color = ["red","blue","green"], shape=["square", "circle"]}
 */
 System.out.println(map.containsValue("square")); //This return false
 System.out.println(map.values().contains("square")); //This return false also
```

I always get false when I use containsValue() or contains() method. Anybody know why and can give me suggestions, please?

Thanks
Ed

Comment: The `Map#values()` returns a `Collection<ArrayList<String>>`, not a `ArrayList<String>` or so as you seemed to expect. A string `"square"`  can never equal any `ArrayList<String>`.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using a `List` rather than a `Set`? Can you have duplicates? I only ask because the `contains` method on `List` is `O(n)` and the same method on `Set` is `O(1)`.

Comment: @ Borris the Spider: hmm..actually the values in the list will be unique, so I guess using set is better..Thx for bringing it up..would it be the same way as above though, to see if this map contains a value? Thx

Comment: You would use one of the methods suggested below, basically loop over the `Map` and check whether any of the `Set`s contain your value. You should also [program to the interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface) so your `Map` should be `Map<String, Collection<String>>`. That way you can select the best `Collection` for the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're testing to see whether the map contains a String, "square"-- but the values in your map are ArrayList<String> objects.

If you know that you're looking for a shape, you can first get the "shape" list, and test to see whether it contains the specific shape "square".

```
  ArrayList<String> shapes = map.get("shape");
  boolean containsSquare = shapes.contains("square");
```

Comment: Thx! Now I know why.. :D

Comment: You're welcome. And welcome to StackOverflow. You can *upvote* answers you find useful by clicking on the up-triangle to the left. You can *accept* the most useful answer by clicking on the checkmark to the left.

Answer (score 2):

Something like below would work

```
 Map<String,ArrayList<String>> map=new TreeMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
            Collection<ArrayList<String>> values=map.values();
            for(ArrayList<String> list:values)
            {
                list.contains("text_to_search")
                {

                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean valueExists(String value){
for(Map.Entry<String,ArrayList<String>> entry : treeMap.entrySet()) {
  String key = entry.getKey();
  ArrayList<String> values = entry.getValue();
  for (String str:values){
     if (value.equals(str)){
         return true;
     }
  }

}
return false;
}
```

Comment: Your generics aren't quite right, `Map.Entry<String,String>` should be `Map.Entry<String,ArrayList<String>>`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider oh I just edited my post to make the correction.